React-Native can't find function, but it's there
I'm developing an app with React-Native for Android. The app was supposed to use the ML Kit PoseDetection API of Google to count reps of an exercise. Right now I just want the app to open the camera, use the detection on me and draw lines on the camera image so that I know the pose detection works. I used the following article of medium.com as a model: https://medium.com/dogtronic/real-time-pose-detection-in-react-native-using-mlkit-e1819847c340
The whole code is written for iOS, so I had to make a few adjustments for the android system. I admit: I used ChatGPT for this because I'm not familiar with Java, Kotlin etc.
The gradle build is always successful.
First my package.json:
{
  "name": "PoseDetection",
  "displayName": "PoseDetection",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native-worklets-core": "1.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.3.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^4.0.5",
    "react-native-worklets-core": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.84",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

and the main part of build.gradle in android\app:
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.posedetection"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.posedetection"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native:+")
    implementation("com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.3")
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:18.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection-accurate:18.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:vision-common:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:vision-interfaces:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:camera:16.0.0-beta3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-vision-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-worklets-core')

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

Like I said, I used ChatGPT most of the time. It told me to create 2 files:
PoseDetectionModule.java:
public class PoseDetectionModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private final PoseDetector poseDetector;

  public PoseDetectionModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      super(reactContext);
      PoseDetectorOptions options = new PoseDetectorOptions.Builder()
              .setDetectorMode(PoseDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
              .build();
      poseDetector = PoseDetection.getClient(options);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
      return "PoseDetection";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void detectPose(Bitmap bitmap, Promise promise) {
      InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0);
      poseDetector.process(image)
              .addOnSuccessListener(
                      pose -> {
                          WritableMap poseData = Arguments.createMap();
                          List<PoseLandmark> landmarks = pose.getAllPoseLandmarks();
                          for (PoseLandmark landmark : landmarks) {
                              String landmarkName = getLandmarkTypeString(landmark.getLandmarkType());
                              WritableMap position = Arguments.createMap();
                              PointF3D position3D = landmark.getPosition3D();
                              position.putDouble("x", position3D.getX());
                              position.putDouble("y", position3D.getY());
                              position.putDouble("z", position3D.getZ());
                              poseData.putMap(landmarkName, position);
                          }
                          promise.resolve(poseData);
                      })
              .addOnFailureListener(
                      e -> {
                          promise.reject("Pose Detection Error", e);
                      });
  }

  private String getLandmarkTypeString(int landmarkType) {
      switch (landmarkType) {
          case PoseLandmark.NOSE:
              return "NOSE";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_EYE_INNER:
              return "LEFT_EYE_INNER";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_EYE:
              return "LEFT_EYE";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_EYE_OUTER:
              return "LEFT_EYE_OUTER";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EYE_INNER:
              return "RIGHT_EYE_INNER";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EYE:
              return "RIGHT_EYE";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EYE_OUTER:
              return "RIGHT_EYE_OUTER";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_EAR:
              return "LEFT_EAR";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_EAR:
              return "RIGHT_EAR";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_MOUTH:
              return "LEFT_MOUTH";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_MOUTH:
              return "RIGHT_MOUTH";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER:
              return "LEFT_SHOULDER";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER:
              return "RIGHT_SHOULDER";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW:
              return "LEFT_ELBOW";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW:
              return "RIGHT_ELBOW";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST:
              return "LEFT_WRIST";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST:
              return "RIGHT_WRIST";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_PINKY:
              return "LEFT_PINKY";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_PINKY:
              return "RIGHT_PINKY";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_INDEX:
              return "LEFT_INDEX";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_INDEX:
              return "RIGHT_INDEX";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_THUMB:
              return "LEFT_THUMB";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_THUMB:
              return "RIGHT_THUMB";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP:
              return "LEFT_HIP";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP:
              return "RIGHT_HIP";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE:
              return "LEFT_KNEE";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE:
              return "RIGHT_KNEE";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE:
              return "LEFT_ANKLE";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ANKLE:
              return "RIGHT_ANKLE";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_HEEL:
              return "LEFT_HEEL";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HEEL:
              return "RIGHT_HEEL";
          case PoseLandmark.LEFT_FOOT_INDEX:
              return "LEFT_FOOT_INDEX";
          case PoseLandmark.RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX:
              return "RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX";
          default:
              return "UNKNOWN";
      }
  }
}

PoseDetectionPackage.java:
public class PoseDetectionPackage implements ReactPackage {

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
                              ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    modules.add(new PoseDetectionModule(reactContext));

    return modules;
  }

}

I returned the package I created in MainApplication.kt:
package com.posedetection

import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage
import com.posedetection.PoseDetectionPackage 

import java.util.Arrays
import com.mrousavy.camera.react.CameraPackage;
import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage
import com.worklets.WorkletsPackage

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

    private val mReactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost = object : ReactNativeHost(this) {
        override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG
        }

        override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> {
            return Arrays.asList<ReactPackage>(
                MainReactPackage(),
                PoseDetectionPackage(), // Füge diese Zeile hinzu
                RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
                ReanimatedPackage(),
                CameraPackage(),
                SvgPackage(),
                WorkletsPackage()
            )
        }

        override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String {
            return "index"
        }

    }

    override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost
        get() = mReactNativeHost

    o }verride fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false)
        // for using flipper just in case
    }
}

And then there is my App.tsx in my project folder:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, useFrameProcessor, useCameraDevice } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import Animated, { useAnimatedProps } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Svg, { Line } from 'react-native-svg';
import { useSharedValue } from 'react-native-worklets-core';
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { PoseDetection } = NativeModules;

const AnimatedLine = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Line);

export function __poseDetection(frame: any): any {
  'worklet';
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    PoseDetection.detectPose(frame, (result: any) => {
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

const usePosition = (pose: any, valueName1: string, valueName2: string) => {
  return useAnimatedProps(
    () => ({
      x1: pose.value[valueName1]?.x ?? 0,
      y1: pose.value[valueName1]?.y ?? 0,
      x2: pose.value[valueName2]?.x ?? 0,
      y2: pose.value[valueName2]?.y ?? 0,
    }),
    [pose],
  );
};


const defaultPose = {
  leftShoulder: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  rightShoulder: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  leftElbow: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  rightElbow: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  leftWrist: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  rightWrist: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  leftHip: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  rightHip: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  leftKnee: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  rightKnee: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  leftAnkle: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  rightAnkle: { x: 0, y: 0 },
};

const App = () => {
  const pose = useSharedValue(defaultPose);

  const leftWristToElbowPosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftWrist', 'leftElbow');
  const leftElbowToShoulderPosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftElbow', 'leftShoulder');
  const leftShoulderToHipPosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftShoulder', 'leftHip');
  const leftHipToKneePosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftHip', 'leftKnee');
  const leftKneeToAnklePosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftKnee', 'leftAnkle');

  const rightWristToElbowPosition = usePosition(pose, 'rightWrist', 'rightElbow');
  const rightElbowToShoulderPosition = usePosition(pose, 'rightElbow', 'rightShoulder');
  const rightShoulderToHipPosition = usePosition(pose, 'rightShoulder', 'rightHip');
  const rightHipToKneePosition = usePosition(pose, 'rightHip', 'rightKnee');
  const rightKneeToAnklePosition = usePosition(pose, 'rightKnee', 'rightAnkle');

  const shoulderToShoulderPosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftShoulder', 'rightShoulder');
  const hipToHipPosition = usePosition(pose, 'leftHip', 'rightHip');

  const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();

  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
    'worklet';
    const poseObject = __poseDetection(frame);

    const xFactor = dimensions.width / frame.width;
    const yFactor = dimensions.height / frame.height;

    const poseCopy = { ...defaultPose };

    Object.keys(poseObject).forEach((v) => {
      poseCopy[v] = {
        x: poseObject[v].x * xFactor,
        y: poseObject[v].y * yFactor,
      };
    });

    pose.value = poseCopy;
  }, []);

  const device = useCameraDevice('front');

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkPermissions = async () => {
      await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
    };
    checkPermissions();
  }, []);

  if (device == null) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Camera
        frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        device={device}
        isActive={true}
      />
      <Svg
        height={Dimensions.get('window').height}
        width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
        style={styles.linesContainer}>
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={leftWristToElbowPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={leftElbowToShoulderPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={leftShoulderToHipPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={leftHipToKneePosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={leftKneeToAnklePosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={rightWristToElbowPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={rightElbowToShoulderPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={rightShoulderToHipPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={rightHipToKneePosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={rightKneeToAnklePosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={shoulderToShoulderPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
        <AnimatedLine animatedProps={hipToHipPosition} stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
      </Svg>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linesContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  },
});

export default App;

I know it's a lot of code but I think they are necessary for my problem.
I get the following error:

Why does it say it doesn't exist? I can't tell if my pose detection just simply doesn't work, the function is coded wrong or I just imported something wrong.
I tried to define '__poseDetection' in a different way to see if there is a logic issue, but the error still appears no matter what I do
I checked the import of the PoseDetectionModule in App.tsx according to the directions of React Native and it seems to be fine
I tried it by adding debugging commands, but I get nothing useful or even nothing
I will probably create a post on GitHub as well because this issue was supposed to be a project for my university so it's quite important

Sorry to say that, but "I used ChatGPT for this because I'm not familiar with Java, Kotlin etc." there's your problem.

Yeah I expected that. I deserved this answer. Touché. So do you have any solutions?

For the error from RN, I see that mentioned about the property __poseDetection doesn't exist. So you can try to remove __ out of your function, just poseDetection is enough, As I remember, sometimes JS uses the prefix __ to handle some special variables.
If it still does not work, try to log the __poseDetection and see what that (function or something else) is.
It's quite weird, why you define 'worklet' without any variable gain to.
